# How do I save active document through POST request from Adobe CEP?

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I'm working with [Adobe CEP](https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/Getting-Started-guides) (it lets developers create windowed extensions for Adobe CC products). I am working on Adobe Illustrator. Is there a way to send the active document (in .ai or .pdf or .png format) in the request body of a HTTP POST request?

Method I've tried:
Save the document using '*app.activeDocument.saveAs*' in the user's local folder. In the next step the user needs to add this file in a form field and submit the form. I've followed the steps for the saving process from [here](https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/Getting-Started-guides/blob/master/Exporting%20files%20from%20the%20host%20app/readme.md)

In this method, the user has to do an extra step of adding the file in the form field. It'd be helpful for me if we can send the file directly from the ExtendScript file or from the JS wrapper file on click of a button

Comment: I'm not sure about .ai, .pdf and .png but the old not compressed .eps or .ps formats are simply text ASCII files. If you can send a text file you can send a .esp/.ps file as well. And I saw in the wild some scripts to read binary files, etc: https://github.com/ten-A/Extend_Script_experimentals (readBin.jsxinc) I suppose it's able to read any file (.ai, .eps, etc) and probably you can convert it bin>ascii, then send it and convert back: ascii>bin. I haven't tried them, though

Comment: Pass the file name through an event and then open the file within your plugin via the cep structure which can then be sent as a string in the post request.